# rollback transaction based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I want to abort batch sql query transactions if column value is less than or equal to user's input value and alert user.

Here's what happens:

- available_qty value is subtracted from user's input qty value and the value is updated in food_menu table.
- user's order records are inserted into food_order table.

Here's my query:

```
    foreach($menuData as $item=>$qty)
    {
        if(empty($qty) || $qty == '0')
            continue;
        $sqlArray[] = "INSERT INTO food_order 
        (user_id, item_id, quantity, order_type, updated_on, updated_by, created_by, created_on)
        VALUES ($uid, $item, $qty, '$menu_type', NOW(), $uid, $uid, NOW())";
        $sqlArray[] = "UPDATE food_menu SET available_qty = IF($qty >= available_qty, available_qty - $qty, available_qty) WHERE item_id = $item AND type = '$menu_type' AND DATE(updated_on) = CURRENT_DATE";
    }
    return (boolean) $this->db->exec($sqlArray);
```

1. if `$qty` value is greater than `available_qty` field value, I want to abort the whole series of transactions in `$sqlArray[]`.

Can I do that in the query itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a much better approach is to check the available quantity with remaining quantity before the start of your insert and update statement. But for the sake of information you can try the following:

Create a before update trigger on food_menu table. In the trigger check the available quantity of it is negative meaning the order quantity is more than available quantity then use the `SIGNAL` statement to raise an error which you will have to catch in your code and do the rollback and show appropriate message to the user.